# ASUS: "Winflash does not support this BIOS update."

Tags: bios, uefi, asus-laptop

I'm trying to flash a new BIOS/UEFI firmware on my ASUS UX330UA. It currently has firmware version 300.

#### Easy Flash 3 (inside the current firmware)

Using `EZ Flash 3` (booting to setup), I can browse the folders on my USB key, but cannot see any files. Why can I only see directories, but not files?

### Windows

I have already removed and re-installed the latest ATK, and also installed the latest version of `Winflash` from the `Driver and Tools` tab under `Support`.

When I run `Winflash`, I get the following error:

[image: Winflash error]

How can I flash the most up-to-date BIOS/UEFI firmware?

Answer (score 2):

It appears certain versions of `EZ Flash` will not display any filenames unless their extension is `.CAP` or `.ROM`.

The file that I downloaded was named:

`UX330UAK-AS.302`

I made two copies of this file, namely:

```
UX330UAK-AS302.ROM
UX330UAK-AS302.CAP
```

Both of these copied files with "correct" extensions were then shown in `EZ Flash 3`, and I could successfully update the firmware.

Interestingly, it seems this is an unlisted bug - the version of `EZ Flash 3` in the new firmware that I flashed showed all files, regardless of extension.

Regarding updating via Windows, I can only assume that `Winflash` needs to be updated to support the UX330, which is newer than the filestamps on the latest version at the time of writing.